# Error when draw signature when i use react-signature-canvas component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas, next.js, signature

In my project i use react 18.2.0, next 13.0.3 and typescript 4.7.4.

I use
`import SignatureCanvas from 'react-signature-canvas';` v1.0.6

This is how i have it.

```
  const sigCanvas = useRef<SignatureCanvas>(null);

  const [signature, setSignature] = useState<string>('');
  let lastInvokeTime = 0;
  const throttleInterval = 16;

  const handleSignature = () => {
    const currentTime = Date.now();
    if (currentTime - lastInvokeTime > throttleInterval) {
      if (sigCanvas.current) {
        const canvas = sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas();
        const signature = canvas.toDataURL();
        setSignature(signature);
      }
      lastInvokeTime = currentTime;
    }
  };

  const [imageURL, setImageURL] = useState('');

  const create = () => {
    if (sigCanvas.current) {
      const URL = sigCanvas.current.getTrimmedCanvas().toDataURL('image/png');
      setImageURL(URL);
      setOpenModal(false);
    }
  };
```

And this in HTML section

```
                    <SignatureCanvas
                      penColor="black"
                      onBegin={handleSignature}
                      minWidth={1}
                      maxWidth={3}
                      canvasProps={{
                        className:
                          'mt-10 w-full h-[200px] border-2 border-solid border-border_grey rounded-[10px] ',
                      }}
                      ref={sigCanvas}
                    />
```

The problem is that, in my localhost this is working perfectly, but when i go to pre or production, i see this when i draw. When i click, i want it to draw a single line to create a signature, but when i click and try to draw, multiple dots are shown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6alTn.gif)

How can i fix that ? Or how can i do it without implementing react-signature-canvas ?

I tried other components and importing react-signature-canvas-react17-compatible. I also tried a debouncing mechanism, which is the 'lastInvokeTime' and 'throttleInterval',...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the issue of `react-signature-canvas` as it is the React wrapper of `signature_pad` package. I have also this kind of weird stuffs in my Next.js application because of **swc Minification**. But, it's working fine in `create-react-app`.

Solution – Add `swcMinify: false` in `next.config.js`

Ref:- [**GitHub issues**](https://github.com/agilgur5/react-signature-canvas/issues/95)